# Flutter Edit Json data in SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I have saved json data in `SharedPreferences` like this

```
storage.setString("user", userInfo);
```

now I want to edit value inside `userInfo` which consist of `name` & `phone` number ,
so what I can do to change the value like the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all import the convert library;

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

get your jsonString

```
String jsonString = await storage.getString("user");
```

and decode it to Dart;

```
var yourJson = json.decode(jsonString);
```

Edit your json and convert it to String again;

```
String editedJsonString = json.encode(yourJson);
```

finally save it to shared with same key;

```
storage.setString("user", editedJsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// get your json
var source = prefs.getString('user');
var json = jsonDecode(source);

// make changes
json['userInfo'] = {
  'name': 'new name',
  'phoneNo': 'new number'
};

// put it back
prefs.setString('user', jsonEncode(json));
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, I also added a way to show how you can edit your json file.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your effort for sure  <3  , so is it the best way to edit the user profile ?

Comment: I am not sure what the context is here, so can't recommend anything without seeing your app logic.